Copying database and authentication fails?
I have django project which has database on aws RDS.
I can login django account correctly with this database.
Now I copied the database with command.
PGPASSWORD=XXXXXX createdb -U dbuser -h kkk.cgrxw5ome4nb.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -T old_db new_db 

It copies the database correctly, but I can not login any accounts with new database.
It says password is uncorrect [auth] Error! Password wrong
However I just copied the database, and username and password is completely same
old database;
select username,password from defapp_customuser where id=1;
 username |                                         password                                         
----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 admin    | pbkdf2_sha256$600000$bZ2UvAJc7cwJMFyk63hlLO$h8/Y2lFZTkwbghyvM/rliyBxwQxF2dMMSqk5tfFqqyo=

new database:
select username,password from defapp_customuser where id=1;
 username |                                         password                                         
----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 admin    | pbkdf2_sha256$600000$bZ2UvAJc7cwJMFyk63hlLO$h8/Y2lFZTkwbghyvM/rliyBxwQxF2dMMSqk5tfFqqyo=

is there any problem?
Class MyAuthBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        logger.info("[auth] 2.Try Django auth backend is Auth")
        try:
            user = m.CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except m.CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            logger.info("[auth] Error! Django user can not be found")
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
            else:
                logger.info("[auth] Error! Password wrong")


check the parameter groups and found the data.

I have the same SECRET_KEY in the settings.py
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-^pktcneebsjtv(mnt2-wps07t$$1syoykvXXXXXXXX'


More checking......
My current user is like this (made in old database)
>>> print(m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin").username,m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin").password)
admin pbkdf2_sha256$600000$bZ2UvAJc7cwJMFyk63hlLO$h8/Y2lFZTkwbghyvM/rliyBxwQxF2dMMSqk5tfFqqyo=

then make new users admin2 and admin3 with createsuperuser and use the same password.
It shows,
>>> print(m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin2").username,m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin2").password)

admin2 pbkdf2_sha256$600000$4U8Ng588QgJPF2XDgkoTMj$Y7/YmN/ObZqorUlr4V/I7pwgiC+59BGOcmBapVjI1aY=

>>> print(m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin3").username,m.CustomUser.objects.get(username="admin3").password)

admin3 pbkdf2_sha256$600000$8h5ZeiwPxuA5YKD78Jwuad$R7VcCxvj5x+wRCT3jbeAtOGIjg2MO1uFhyERJPZVYvk=

every user has different password hash, is it correct behaivor?

You probably didn't create a pg_hba.conf entry.

Thank you I updated the article, however in this case I don't create the new RDS instance, just copy the database. Is it relevant?

Where is user.check_password defined?  Is that in some standard Django library?

To the close-voter, this is not about authenticating to the database, this about using the database to store the password hash for some user-defined authentication scheme (which means it really isn't about the database at all).

Is the SECRET_KEY on production the same? Since this is used to hash the password.

 user.check_password is from CustomUser model and CustomUser is inherit of AbstractUser like class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

If duplicating data from database completed correctly, there must not be any such problems with it, if also the project settings were not changed, like DJANGO_SECRET_KEY or some other Django settings, which are changing authorization behavior. I can just recommend you to do this all again, and ensure that nothing on db copy, and the project settings are not changed.

Thank you very mcuh . SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-^pktcneebsjtv(mnt2-wps07tXXXXXXXXXXXX in settings.py is same.

I updated the article.
